# Function for when new custom post type is created should do something

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, codex

I've been searching in the codex from wordpress and search through google but didn't find any function or any code that can help me.

I want to build a conditional that when there is a new custom post type should do something automatically(in one case specific create a marker in a map).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: When a Custom Post of a Post Type is created? The [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook is well enough for that, checking against the `$post->post_type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something on a post creation with the action `save_post_`...

```
$customPostType = "custom";


add_action("save_post_" . $customPostType, function ($post_ID, \WP_Post $post, $update) {

    if (!$update) {
        // creation of the custom post
        // ...

        return;
    }


    // updating of the custom post
    // ...



}, 10, 3);
```